# how to get the Final TPT value from the base table

Tags: t-sql

This is data of one of the material from base table:

```
Material    yyyyww  item_type   TPT
E123        201919  Assembly    7
E123        201919  Assembly    6
E123        201919  Assembly    7
E123        201919  Assembly    7
E123        201919  FG          2
E123        201919  FG          2
E123        201919  FG          1
E123        201919  TEST        7
E123        201919  TEST        4
```

Here, item_type and TPT are key columns which will be needed for calculation of finalTPT as below:

```
MAX(TPT) AssemblyTPT                    7
MAX(TPT) TestTPT                        7
MAX(TPT) FG                             2
Final TPT CEILING((SUM(7+7+2)/7)+1,1)   4 <--final result.
```

I am trying case statements for the calculations but there are multiple materials available. So I need to find 'Final TPT' for each substrate.

Expected output: `4`

Comment: Why do you divide / 7? And what is that 1 after the comma. Ceiling takes 1 parameter only.

Comment: I rolled back your edit - you should keep data samples in the question, not in pictures.

Comment: @forpas, sorry, i used this function in excel. Basically i want next integer value of result of this ((SUM(7+7+2)/7)+1,1)

Comment: Why do you divide / 7?

Comment: @forpas it is a requirement of the solution i need to develop.

Comment: So 7 is a constant in the formula?

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #tempT (Material varchar(10),yyyyww  int,item_type    varchar(10),TPT int    )
-------------Insert---------------
insert into #tempT values('E123'    ,    201919 , 'Assembly'  , 7)
insert into #tempT values('E123'    ,    201919 , 'Assembly'  , 6)
insert into #tempT values('E123'    ,    201919 , 'Assembly'  , 7)
insert into #tempT values('E123'    ,    201919 , 'Assembly'  , 7)
insert into #tempT values('E123'    ,    201919 , 'FG'        , 2)
insert into #tempT values('E123'    ,    201919 , 'FG'        , 2)
insert into #tempT values('E123'    ,    201919 , 'FG'        , 1)
insert into #tempT values('E123'    ,    201919 , 'TEST'      , 7)
insert into #tempT values('E123'    ,    201919 , 'TEST'      , 4)

------------Output-------------
select Material ,ceiling(((sum((MaxTPT)))/7.00)+1)MaxTPT  
 from(select Material,item_type,case when item_type='Assembly' then max(TPT)
when item_type='fg' then max(TPT)
when item_type='TEST' then max(TPT) end MaxTPT from #tempT
group by Material,item_type)a
group by Material
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. It is working as expected. :)